# TextInput in Login/Signup Page is losing focus automatically

Tags: react-native

I am having a page in react-native which is using stack navigator.
When i click on the TextInput it gains focus and loses it automatically after a few seconds.
This hides the keyboard automatically which interrupts my text entering.

When i put the page in top of stack navigator it doesn't loses focus but after i again put it below some pages it again starts to lose focus.

[Video Demo of Issue](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10gx5fdyED7D7xq2Xw_qUdcxRSJlxgEte)

App.js

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
  Carousel: {screen: CarouselScreen},
  Test: {screen: Test},
},
{
  transitionConfig
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: AppStackNavigator
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);
```

Test.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, StyleSheet, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <TextInput style={styles.test} placeholder={"Test"} onBlur={() => console.log("Input Blurred!")} blurOnSumbit={false}/>
          </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    test: {
        height: 100,
        width:200,
        borderColor: '#000000',
        borderWidth: 2
    }
});
```

The TextInput should not loose focus and therefore the keyboard should not hide.

Comment: Do you use scrollview or flatlist in Test.js ?

Comment: No, well i tried using it but no luck.. See what happens in the demo video.. When i put the page on top of stack the problem is solved.

Comment: Delete onBlur={() => console.log("Input Blurred!")} and try again.

Comment: The onBlur method is just used to check whether the textinput is getting out of focus..

Comment: Maybe something to do with stackNavigator.. Not sure though

Comment: What's transitionConfig?

Comment: Transition configuration for page navigation.. Next and back animation..

Comment: show me the code please

Comment: I removed it but still no luck..Here is the code by the way. [Transition Config](https://pastebin.com/nVQFSs48)

Comment: I changed the stackNavigator with switchNavigator and its working fine.. What is the problem with stackNavigator?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use ref prop of the input and then onBlur make it keep focus as follow:

```
 <TextInput 
    style={styles.test} 
    placeholder={"Test"} 
    ref={refs => this.inputRef = refs}
    onBlur={this.keepFocus} 
    blurOnSumbit={false}
/>

keepFocus = () => {
    this.inputRef.focus()
}
```

If you want the focused input as the component mount then do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.keepFocus()
}
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: I tried your method.. See whats happening.. [Video Demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1htISrP0Ckg4RMHDDGS5X9pcEvkm8eai1)

Comment: The keyboard is flickering.As the textinput is getting out of focus the keyboard is dismissing automatically and its forced to focus on the textinput again so its re-apperaing so the flickering.

Comment: Maybe something to do with stackNavigator.. Not sure though

Comment: I changed the stackNavigator with switchNavigator and its working fine.. What is the problem with stackNavigator?